# merging two arrays from a service in angularJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have a problem in merging the Data from my web service that send the id of selected row in my table, and get with this id the data, this is what I get in console:

```
my all Liste [{ I get only the data of finalOperationsList not with the $scope.liste data}]
```

this is my code:

```
.factory('gammeMonatageFactory', function($http,$q){
     var backObject = { getListOperationsById:_getListOperationsById }
     return backObject;

     function _getListOperationsById(val){            
              var defer = $q.defer();
              $http({
                  method : "GET",
                  url : "MyURL/getById:"+val
              }).then(function mySucces(response) {
                  defer.resolve(response.data);
              }, function myError(response) {
                  deferred.reject('Erreur into url '+response);
              });  

              return defer.promise;
     };        
});
```

and this is how I have called the service:

```
$scope.modifierOuCreerArticle = function() {    
     var v = $scope.OperationsList[$scope.OperationsList.length-1].Id;
     gammeMonatageFactory.getListOperationsById(v).then(function(Data){
         $scope.liste= JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(Data));  
         //I get the Data of $scope.liste only here I can't get this Data     outside this call                            
     });
     $scope.listfinal = $scope.finalOperationsList.concat($scope.liste);
     console.log("my all Liste "+$listfinal);
 }
```

any help please to merge the 2 `finalOperationsList` and `liste` arrays
thanks for help

Comment: You are loading $scope.list asynchronously, so $scope.list is still undefined while you are using concat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you merge the two array, the callback from the rest call wasn't executed yet.
So, You should merge the two lists in your callback, when `liste` data is set.
You can initialize the `$scope.listfinal` with an empty array or with some initial data. The view will update in consequence.

```
$scope.modifierOuCreerArticle = function() {    
     var v = $scope.OperationsList[$scope.OperationsList.length-1].Id;
     gammeMonatageFactory.getListOperationsById(v).then(function(Data){
         $scope.liste = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(Data));  
         $scope.listfinal = $scope.finalOperationsList.concat($scope.liste); // concat the arrays when $scope.liste is available                         
     });
     $scope.listfinal = $scope.finalOperationsList; // or initialize the list with empty array;
     console.log("my all Liste " + $listfinal);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Another thing I saw from your code is your `service` has a issue against [promise anti-pattern](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns)

inside the service it is better to be:

```
function _getListOperationsById(val){ 
      //instead of create your own promise object, chaining the promise object returned by $http and return it
      return $http({
          method : "GET",
          url : "MyURL/getById:"+val
      }).then(function mySucces(response) {
          return response.data;
      }, function myError(response) {
          return $q.reject('Erreur into url '+response);
      });  
  };
```

If you don't need to deal with the response in the service as a mid-layer, I suggest to return the result directly :

```
function _getListOperationsById(val){ 
      //instead of create your own promise object, chaining the promise object returned by $http and return it
      return $http({
          method : "GET",
          url : "MyURL/getById:"+val
      });  
  };
```

And the solution has been given by other people, you should merge them together in the returned promise `then()` function.